# cygwin on win7 problem - Could not use curl because "cygcurl-4.dll" is missing

Tags: curl, cygwin

Where do I find it and how do I install it?

Thanks

***Follow-up:***

I did use the full installation and this specific file is not there.

Answer (score 1):

In my installation, it's in the CygWin `bin` directory, and that's a full install with no external stuff. You should ensure that you did a *full* install of your CygWin. I've had enough troubles before with partial installs to ensure I *never* try them again.

---

Based on your update where you state that you did a full install, I can only suggest you try it again. As I said, I did a full install and that file is there in the CygWin `bin` directory.

Do the full install and immediately check for the existence of the file (you can also try to install just the Net and/or Web packages but, as I said, I don't trust partial installs).

I suppose it's possible that Windows or some security package may have removed it as a threat but it depends entirely on what you're running. By checking immediately after install, you can hopefully track down if that's the case. If it's there after full install and not there a day later, you'll know something funny is going on.

And, if it's still there after a couple of weeks, well, you've solved the problem although, like may others, I'd prefer to know the root cause behind the original problem. But I'd be at least moderately happy if the problem just went away :-)

Just ensure that you click on the "rotating arrows" icon on the `All` package until it says `Install`. And I'd also suggest doing it with the latest `setup.exe` from the CygWin site (temporarily renaming your current directory if you want to be able to recover it). The install I did was only about a week ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I installed curl by using setup-x86.exe on a 64 bit Windows 8.1 machine (run setup-x86.exe, search for curl, install *Net curl: Multi....*)

To fix it I just re-ran the installer and searched for curl and installed *Libs libcurl4....* (you can just run the installer and search for *libcurl4*)

Answer (score 0):

If you tried installing curl via setup.exe and you still don't see cygcurl-4.dll in the output of "ls /bin | grep curl", then chances are pretty good that you're using the wrong terminal. If you have a 64-bit machine and you're using setup-x86.exe, you *will* run into this problem. Instead, you need to use the 64-bit version of Cygwin, which is setup-x86_64.exe.

If you're not convinced, here's the output from x86, and the output from x86-64, even when I tried installing curl on both versions:

**x86:**

```
$ ls /bin | grep curl
curl.exe
cygcurl-3.dll
```

**x86_64:**

```
$ ls /bin | grep curl
curl.exe
cygcurl-4.dll
```