# CYGWIN Make help

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, cygwin

Hey guys I installed cygwin on my windows 7 just now With ALL THE PACKAGES (including make). But once i try to use the make command in cygwin it gives me error message: "bash: make: command not found". Wt is this? I deff installed all the packages that came with cygwin.

Comment: Wow. I don't think I've ever seen any one install *all the packages*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know whether Win7 is playing funnies with CygWin since I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803218/cygwin-on-win7-problem-could-not-use-curl-because-cygcurl-4-dll-is-missing) a couple of days ago where it appeared to have removed a DLL.

From the `bash` shell, execute `echo $PATH` and ensure that `/bin` is in there somewhere.

Make sure that you *are* running it from the CygWin `bash` shell rather than a `cmd.exe` window.

Check that `make.exe` exists under your `\cygwin\bin` directory (assuming you installed in `\cygwin`).

If it's not there, re-install (by that, I mean rename the directory and do a full install again, *not* use the reinstall from `setup.exe`)  Check *immediately* after the install to see if it's there.

That's about all I can offer without further info. Let me know the results of those tasks and we can move on further if they don't pan out.

Comment: k i checked. there is no make.exe in bin, just a "makeinfo" file. Idk whats going on. I run cygwin through desktop icon. Any other suggestions?

Comment: also there are a bunch of bins when i execute excho. Im a noob at this so any reason why I don't have make.exe in bin when i know i installed all the packages?

Comment: @user593301, are you _absolutely_ sure you did a full install by clicking once on the `All` package "rotating arrows" icon until it said "install" rather than "default"? Sorry to doubt you but I've been bitten by that before. I have no less than _sixteen_ files in my bin directory starting with the word "make".

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if that helps or is still actual, but I had (years ago, Win XP) similar problems. Then I installed Qt, which came with an option to install CygWin during the installation process. This installation worked without any problems.

So if this is possible, maybe give a try going around your problems by simply letting the Qt installer handle it. (Even if you don't intend to use Qt)

Comment: What? Why would Qt install Cygwin? It installs and uses MinGW. Qt under Cygwin is supported, but as just a regular package, and it doesn't even work perfectly there (QProcess often crashes for example).

Comment: Sorry, Sergey is right, this was MinGW not Cygwin. As said, that was several years back. I installed both then and my memory mixed that up. Didn't use it for much else then a few test.

Comment: so nobody can help me on this? is there anyone else with this issue? I really dont wanna get xp just for this

Comment: @user593301, did you read the paxdiablo's comment? He is probably right in that you haven't really installed all the packages. Run Cygwin setup again (you can do it as many times as you wish) and look carefully - the relevant packages should be marked as "install", not "default" or some other nonsense. It is easy to miss and it is most likely the root of your problem. I have a working Cygwin installation on Windows 7 right here, with no problems, so it's certainly possible.

Comment: I didn't see in all the responses the advice to check your anti-spam quarantines.  Perhaps implicit in the question is that you haven't installed an run make previously, but the continued repeats, and eventual admission that you weren't running cygwin, "make" for doubts.  Normally running of make involves execution patterns which a malware detector considers suspicious, so make may end up quarantined until you put it on the exceptions list.  If you aren't running a malware detector, that could be a problem too.