# Cygwin Make bash command not found

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin, command

I installed cygwin with all the packages on windows 7 64 bit. For some reason the make command is giving me an error: bash make: command not found. I checked and in my bin folder, there is no make.exe. Can anyone help me on this? I really need make to work in CYGWIN. I dont wanna have to go to windows xp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CYGWIN Make help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825317/cygwin-make-help)

Comment: you can try: find / -name make\*

Comment: Please don't post duplicates, especially since you have given no indication that you even tried the suggestions given in the answers to your original question. It makes SO far less useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CYGWIN Make help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825317/cygwin-make-help)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You probably have not installed make. Restart the cygwin installer, search for make, select it and it should be installed. By default the cygwin installer does not install everything for what I remember.

Comment: As a caveat, you can _not_ do this from Programs & Features. It has to be the actual installer.

Answer (score 88):

While instaling (updating) check 'Devel' to 'Install', it will install a lot of MB but helps. I don't have time to check which exacly I (we) need.

[image: CYGWIN INSTALL STEP]

Comment: That would install unnecessary things. You only should look for gcc devel and make packages...

Answer (score 14):

follow some steps below:

1. open cygwin setup again
2. choose catagory on view tab
3. fill "make" in search tab
4. expand devel
5. find "make: a GNU version of the 'make' ultility", click to install
6. Done!

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the installer again
2. Do the initial setup.
3. Under library - go to devel.
4. under devel scroll and find make.
5. install all of library with name make.
6. click next, will take some time to install.
7. this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

when selecting packages at installation or update  search for 'make' in searchbox  and select the boxes showing 'make' and also 'gcc' mostly found in devel package.

Answer (score 2):

if you have `apt-cyg` , then you are done with one command

```
apt-cyg install make
```

if you don't have `apt-cyg` , then install it as it will simplify your life.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was due to several installations of cygwin.

Check the link (the icon) that you click on to start the terminal. In case it does not point to the directory of your updated cygwin installation, you have the wrong installation of cygwin. When updating, double check the location of cygwin, and start exactly this instance of cygwin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15586254)

Comment: I think this does provide an answer. I had the same problem as the author and this solved it. I rephrased the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Follow these steps:

1. Goto the installer once again.
2. Do the initial setup.
3. Select all the libraries by clicking and selecting install (the one already installed will show reinstall, so don't install them).
4. Click next.
5. The installation will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too. Look up to the left side, and select (full). (Make), (gcc) and many others will appear. You will be able to chose the search bar to find them easily.