# How can i install gearman php extension on Windows OS?

Tags: php, windows, operating-system, php-extension, gearman

Please anybody help me out in installing gearman php extension on windows xp. I have xampp 1.7.7 installed on my system and i have installed Cygwin, libevent-1.4.14b-stable and gearmand on my system. Please let me know what more is needed to install gearman-1.0.2 php extension. As when i run the gearman-1.0.2 on cygwin terminal throwing error of command not found.

Comment: Finde here for pear extension -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628109/3575770

Comment: You can find detailed steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628109/3575770)

Answer (score 5):

> to install Gearman with PHP Extension in CentOS or Debian see
>   [How to install Gearman with PHP Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982921/how-to-install-gearman-with-php-extension/30592132#30592132)

**Installing and Updating Cygwin Package**

from: https://cygwin.com/install.html

**Install the Latest GCC and make via Cygwin**

- http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/cygwin/part2/

[image]

**Install wget via Cygwin**

- https://superuser.com/questions/693284/wget-command-not-working-in-cygwin

[image]

**Install libevent**

```
   wget https://github.com/libevent/libevent/releases/download/release-2.0.22-stable/libevent-2.0.22-stable.tar.gz
    tar -zxvf libevent-2.0.22-stable.tar.gz
    cd libevent-2.0.22-stable
    ./configure
    make
    make install
```

**install gearmand and libgearman**

```
wget https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/archive/1.1.12.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
cd gearmand-1.1.12
./configure
make
make install
```

**install pecl-gearman**

```
pecl install gearman
```

**Resources**

- http://www.cppblog.com/guojingjia2006/archive/2012/12/28/196743.html
- [Cygwin Make bash command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828388/cygwin-make-bash-command-not-found)
- https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/5270256
- [How to install Gearman with PHP Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982921/how-to-install-gearman-with-php-extension/30592132#30592132)

Comment: The launchpad link expired, you can find the exact same gearmand package on Github: `https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/archive/1.1.12.tar.gz`

Comment: Same goes for the libevent link, here's an updated link. `https://github.com/libevent/libevent/releases/download/release-2.0.22-stable/libevent-2.0.22-stable.tar.gz`