# Windows cygwin gearman ./configure shows "configure: error: Unable to find libevent" error

Tags: php, windows, cygwin, gearman, libevent

I am trying to install gearman http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/

I downloaded "libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz" and extracted in cygwin's home/libs directory (I created a libs directory myself) where there is also "gearmand-1.1.5". Then, inside the libevent directory I did:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

After installing libevent, I changed to gearman directory and did:

```
./configure
```

This resulted in "configure: error: Unable to find libevent". Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A moment ago, I solved this problem. It's because when we complete to compile "libevent", it will generate the lib files in ./usr/local/lib. This path is not contained in environment variable——PATH. So, we have to copy it to "usr/local/bin", and then, it works well...

Comment: I am not getting any lib file

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install libevent-devel
```

And then configure and make

As answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33368/trying-to-install-gearman-on-centos-and-configure-cannot-find-event-h-even-th

Answer (score 0):

For me:

1. I installed Cygwin in `C:\cygwin64\`
2. downloaded `libevent-2.0.22-stable` into `C:\cygwin64\home\user1`

   ```
   cd libevent-2.0.22-stable
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```

   -this creates `.libs` folder and fills it with created output
3. I copied everything from `C:\cygwin64\home\user1\libevent-2.0.22-stable\.libs`
   into `C:\cygwin64\lib` but moved the `.dll` files into `C:\cygwin64\bin`
4. I downloaded `C:\cygwin64\home\user1\gearmand-1.1.12` and same trick again:

   ```
   cd gearmand-1.1.12
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```

Hope this helps. You might want to also check this:
 [How can i install gearman php extension on Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373363/1168156)

UPDATE: note, you might need to go for lower version, as higher ones can have some compilation problems, see https://gist.github.com/mnapoli/5270256

UPDATE 2: it's insanely hard to get the PECL extension work on Windows, and I've ended with this neat trick: get PEAR to work, then get `pear install Net_Gearman-0.2.3` and in code that uses class `GearmanClient`:

```
require_once("Net/Gearman/Client.php");
use Net_Gearman_Client as GearmanClient;

... new GearmanClient([$serverId]);
```