# Installing gearman PHP extension on Windows using cygwin and pecl

Tags: php, windows, cygwin, pecl, gearman

There is only a handful of threads on installing gearman on Windows, especially the gearman PHP extension. I have not found a solution yet. If anyone found a solution to get gearman PHP extension working on Windows, please comment on this thread.

I came across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373363/how-can-i-install-gearman-php-extension-on-windows-os) on `pecl install gearman`. When attempting to install [Gearman PHP extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/gearman) through cygwin using [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/), the installation failed with the following error.

```
$ pecl search gearman
Retrieving data...0%
Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=======================================
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
gearman 1.1.2 (stable)        PHP wrapper to libgearman

$ pecl install gearman
pecl/gearman requires PHP (version >= 5.1.0, version <= 6.0.0, excluded versions: 6.0.0), installed version is 7.1.12 
No valid packages found 
install failed
```

I checked PHP version and it is 5.6.3. Where is that installed version 7.1.12 coming from?

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.31 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2017 22:24:51)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Related thread: [How can i install gearman php extension on Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373363/how-can-i-install-gearman-php-extension-on-windows-os)

Comment: 1. Cygwin is bad at being a *nix environment, you should use a linux VM. 2. Windows is bad as a PHP environment and, unless your ultimate deployment/production environment is going to be Windows, you should use a linux VM. 3. PECL gearman is abandonware, and gearman itself is awful, use an AMQP server [eg: RabbitMQ] and a PHP AMQP lib [eg: php-amqplib]. 4. PHP 5.6 End-of-Life is coming, use PHP7.

Comment: Thanks, @Sammitch. We develop on Windows, but deploy on Linux.

Comment: Don't do that. Use something like Vagrant and replicate your production environment to a local VM so that: 1. You have a sane linux env. 2. Your dev and prod environments match. 3. Using something like [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) allows you to spin up new, *clean* dev environments easily. You still use "Desktop OS of choice" to run your IDE, but your code/tests/etc run in an environment that matches production.