# How to install Gearman PHP extension on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, php-extension, pecl, gearman

**Background**:
1. [How can i install gearman php extension on Windows OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373363)
2. [Installing gearman PHP extension on Windows using cygwin and pecl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47822264/1168156)

Following the answer in 1. question, I've made my cygwin work, downloaded and compiled gearman, and got the first gearman worker example to work:

[image]

**Problem**:
To run the same example from PHP script, I still need PHP extension. Somewhere I've seen that I might get to install PECL extension using PEAR, so:

1. I've downloaded go-pear.phar into `C:\...\php5.6.16`
2. ran `php go-pear.phar`
3. installed PEAR in `system` mode -> success

Now I can do: `C:\...\php5.6.16>pecl install gearman` which gives:

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl         
channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading gearman-1.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download gearman-1.1.2.tgz (30,961 bytes)
.........done: 30,961 bytes
3 source files, building
ERROR: The DSP gearman.dsp does not exist.
```

Which would indeed be a sorcery if it worked, as that extension should be probably built/compiled accordingly to PHP itself. What is the least painful way to make this work? Is there a way how to do this without installing Visual Studio? I've also seen [Net_Gearman PEAR package](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_Gearman/) that might perhaps be wrapped / tweaked to be used just as the PECL one?

I'm currently using WAMP3.1.1 with PHP5.6.16 it comes with + [VC15 x64 Thread Safe PHP7.2.2](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.2), need Gearman to work with at least one of those two. Any help appreciated

Comment: here I have given for pear extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628109/3575770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I've followed these 2 guides:</strike>

- https://www.sitepoint.com/compiling-php-from-source-on-windows/
- https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

**1.** I've downloaded:

- Visual Studio 2012
- .NET Framework 4.7.1 (which at the end just flashed a message that it's already installed)
- Windows SDK _X_EN_DVD.iso
- php-sdk-binary-tools-20110915.zip
- deps-5.6-vc11-x64.7z (dependencies)
- [php-src-php-5.6.16.zip (GitHub release)](https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-5.6.16.zip)

**2.** Compiled PHP

- (note this is all from Native Tools Command Prompt, I didn't even actually start VS at all)
- used just `configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-pdo`

**3.** Tried to compile PECL Gearman

- found out it can't really be done on Windows

**4.** Found Gearman wrapper for Windows:

## [mhlavac/gearman on GitHub](https://github.com/mhlavac/gearman)

Comment: What about extension? How did you install it on windows? I'm facing same problem, also in wamp 3.1.x