# How do I install cURL on cygwin (latest versions checked in setup - cyg complains missing .DLL)

Tags: curl, cygwin, libcurl

There are other posts about this from 2011 but they do not have answers marked accepted (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803218/cygwin-on-win7-problem-could-not-use-curl-because-cygcurl-4-dll-is-missing)).

My Cygwin complains about the missing .DLL as follows:

```
    /usr/bin/curl.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygmetalink-3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

Re-run `setup.exe`, choose Install from Internet, and allow it to install all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with this steps:

1. create /usr/local/tmp directory
2. cd /usr/local/tmp
3. Download libmetalink3-0.1.2-1.tar.bz2 from ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/x86/release/libmetalink/libmetalink3/
4. bunzin libmetalink3-0.1.2-1.tar.bz2
5. cd /
6. tar xvf /usr/local/tmp/libmetalink3-0.1.2-1.tar

Now try run curl:

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.29.0 (i686-pc-cygwin) libcurl/7.29.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.26 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP Metalink
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the Cygwin installer and install **libmetalink3** library. That should do the trick.